# getting the moment of unchanging cursor position X and Y in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse

I want to get the moment of the unchanging cursor position. I mean when mouse stops, I want to do something. But I will do this many times.I used dispatcher timer. But It doesnt allow me to do same thing inside of that. Example:

```
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += (sd, args) => // this is triggered when mouse stops.
        {

            if (a== b)
            {
               I do something here }; // it works until here.

            }


         timer2.Tick += (sd, args ) => // // It doesnt allow me to put this timer here.

         {
               I will do something here when mouse stops.
         }
         };
```

Comment: where are you declaring timer2..? is this code that you understand.. please format the code better too..

Comment: What does the error for "It doesnt allow me to put this timer here." say? 
also, do you need to close your timer2 lambda expression with a semicolon like you did for timer?

Comment: of course, this is not the whole code. I just tried to give the idea. I declared all the things. This code I mean the whole code is working if the first timer timer.Tick is the only timer. When I add the second timer, it doesnt work. It just gives the red underlines on the second timer's (sd,args) => part.

Comment: Your formatting is tripping me up. Can you go over it one more time?

Comment: What are you doing when the mouse stops???  How long does the mouse need to stay in the same coordinates?

Comment: Do not focus on what I do when mouse stops. Lets say I call function DoSth(); The main idea is to detect when mouse stops. Ok, I created one menu and when mouse stops, menu pops up.So far, Menu opens when mouse stops with timer.Tick which is on the code above. Then, the next mouse stop will occur with the timer2.Tick, but I cant make it work. The whole idea is to detect when mouse stops. I mean when X and Y are stable. Is everything more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1); /* Try to use larger value suitable for you. */
        timer.Tick += (sd, args) => // This is triggered every 1sec.
        {
            Point currentpoint = /* Define current position of mouse here */ null;
            if (lastpoint == currentpoint)
            {
                /* Do work if mouse stays at same */

                /* { //EDIT*/

                /* I haven't tried this, but it might work */
                /* I'm assuming that you will always do new work when mouse stays */
                DispatcherTimer timer2 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), /* Tick interval */
                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, /* Dispatcher priority */ 
                    (o, a) => /* This is called on every tick */
                    {
                        // Your logic goes here 
                        // Also terminate timer2 after work is done.
                        timer2.Stop();
                        timer2 = null;
                    },
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher /* Current dispatcher to run timer on */
                    );
                timer2.Start(); /* Start Timer */

                /* } //EDIT */

            }
            lastpoint = currentpoint;
        };
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: This solution is closer to my problem. Thank you. But, Can you try to use 2 timers. This is what I need actually. Because, I do something else in IF part in your code. In IF part, I need to use second timer or I need to catch another mouse stop. I mean, For example: Lets imagine that I call LeftClick() function after timer.Tick occurs. And then I'm going into the one IF condition. Since I'm in IF condition, timer.Tick doesn't work. So, I have to use another timer2.Tick to start counter. Can you simulate how to use another timer in IF condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try to get X and Y mouse position after the mouse has stopped moving for 1 sec. No need for double timers etc. Just register the MouseMove event for your window and reset the timer everytime it moves.

```
    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var position = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        // position.X
        // position.Y

        timer.Stop(); // you don't want any more ticking. timer will start again when mouse moves.
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // restart timer. will not cause ticks.
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Red squiggly lines you say?

```
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
    timer.Tick += (sd, args) => // this is triggered when mouse stops.
    {

        if (a== b)
        {
           I do something here }; // it works until here.

        }


         timer2.Tick += (sd1, args1 ) => // // It doesnt allow me to put this timer here.
         {
               I will do something here when mouse stops.
         }
     };
```

Does this help? I renamed the arguments, since you're redefining them and I have run into red squiggly lines in this case before...

Comment: I haven't thought of renaming:) I was getting the args from somewhere else. I duplicated that one with name sd1,args1 and the new timer with sd1,args1 worked in IF condition. Thank you..Sometimes small things can not be seen as you see :)